# Doubts with parfor in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, parfor

Could you explain me why
the following code with `parfor` in Matlab does not work and how to fix it?

```
R=10;
Power=zeros(2,R); 
parfor s=1:R
    Power(1,s)=1
    Power(2,s)=2;
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because you have 1 variable that is sent to different workers (`power`) and you want to write on it using different cores.

How can you write in the same variable with different workers? who stores the memory? How do workers communicate where did they write and where not? The structure of the code is very important when doing parallel computing, as you need to be aware of what memory you send to what worker. Just choosing a wrong approach in passing variables can make your code slower than the non-parallel one.

The code you show can be changed to:

```
R=10;
Power1=zeros(1,R);
Power2=zeros(1,R); 

parfor s=1:R
    Power1(1,s)=1
    Power2(1,s)=2;
end
Power=[Power1;Power2]
```

I suggest you go to http://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parallel-for-loops-parfor.html
 and read the "concepts" section, especially the [variable types in parfors](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/classification-of-variables-in-parfor-loops.html), that the MATLAB error directs you to.